# Sorting by chosen column in grouped datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, xaml, datagrid

I have a grouped data grid that is bound to a ListCollectionView.
I want to add an option for inner sort (in the groups) by pressing one of the columns.

I wrote the following code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name = "ProjectsDataGrid" ItemSource = "{Binding}" 
     AutoGeneratedColumns = "False"
     CanUserDeleteRows = "False"
     CanUserAddRows = "False"
     CanUserResizeColumns = "True"
     SelectionMode = "Single"
     SelectionUnit = "FullRow"
     CanUserSortColumns = "True"
     Sorting = "ProjectsDataGrid_Sorting"
     >

<... columns info ...>

<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                     <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
                                <Expander.Header>
                                    <DockPanel>
                                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                    </DockPanel>
                                </Expander.Header>
                                <Expander.Content>
                                    <ItemsPresenter />
                                </Expander.Content>
                            </Expander>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>

</DataGrid>
```

When I ran the program I couldn't press the columns and get to the sorting function even though I allowed it in the dataGrid definition, any ideas why?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't do anything when you press on column header? Make sure you don't have CanUserSort="False" for your columns.

Comment: @Ppp yes, I checked again and CanUserSort is "True".

Comment: Okay. Can you share more details then? What's in your ProjectsDataGrid_Sorting?

Comment: @Ppp right now it's an empty function, I can't get to it by pressing the header of the column..I used the same way to override the sorting function in other datagrids and it worked. The only difference is that the current data grid is bound to a ListCollectionView and not to a List<T>, this might be the problem?